# Particular System PDE

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Is there a solution for this system of PDE?

$\Delta f=\frac{-2\lambda}{m}f$

$|\nabla f|^2=(\frac{2\lambda-m\lambda}{m(m-1)})f^2$

where $f$ is a positive scalar function of two variables, $\Delta f$ is the Laplacian of $f$ (i.e., $f_{xx}+f_{yy}$), $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$ (then $|\nabla f|^2=f_x^2+f_y^2$), $\lambda$ is a nonzero constant and $m$ is a constant not zero and not $-1$.

Comment: Its not really a system since there is only one unknown function. Please specify the domain and boundary condition then I can probably provide you a full answer.

Comment: @maxmilgram - yes you are right is only one function ($f$), the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and there is not boundary conditions.

Comment: Do you want a decay at infinity?

Comment: it is not necessary

Comment: Please add more Information to the question such as Are you looking for solutions in the classical sense? Are you looking for a solution for every set of parameters or can $m$ and $\lambda$ be chosen as well? Are you looking for a nontrivial solution? Are there any more restrictions? ...

Comment: Yes, $m$ and $\lambda$ can be chosen as well. Yes, I'm looking for nontrivial solution